# LoadRunner save JSESSIONID returned by server not in html

Tags: loadrunner

the usual way I do manual correlation is to set lef and right boundry as I find it in the html on the initial web-page. 
However, using extended logging in LoadRunner I see that the JSESSIONID is returned from server this way:

```
Action.c(4): Redirecting "http://xxx/xxx/" (redirection depth is 1)      [MsgId: MMSG-26694]

Action.c(4): To location "http://xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx"        [MsgId: MMSG-26693]

Action.c(4): t=3707ms: 384-byte response headers for "http://xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx" (RelFrameId=1,     Internal ID=3)

Action.c(4):     HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily\r\n

Action.c(4):     Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\n

Action.c(4):     Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=b6A10tdvDpwexLDVS4VKGHEX; Path=/xxx\r\n

Action.c(4):     Date: Thu, 17 Jan 2013 12:04:38 GMT\r\n

Action.c(4):     Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT\r\n

Action.c(4):     Pragma: no-cache\r\n

Action.c(4):     Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store\r\n

Action.c(4):     Location: http://xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx;jsessionid=b6A10td

Action.c(4):     vDpwexLDVS4VKGHEX?0\r\n

Action.c(4):     Content-Length: 0\r\n

Action.c(4):     \r\n

Action.c(4): Redirecting
```

How do I capture this value? As it is not in the HTML returned from the server?

BR
Magnus

Comment: BTW: it seems that LR (11.0) takes care of this for me automatically, but I want to be in control of my script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, solved it used this:

```
web_reg_save_param("JSessionID", "LB=JSESSIONID=", "RB=;", LAST);
```

Comment: `web_reg_save_param()` looks in the HTTP headers too. That's why it worked. However, LR handles this automatically, so it may not be necessary. If all you are trying to do is force a logout by removing / not sending the cookie later, you can use `web_cleanup_cookies()`.